# Fuzzy and FuzzyWuzzy: what are the differences in text comparison?

Tags: python, similarity, fuzzy-logic

I have found a lot of information about fuzzy logic, but less information about fuzzywuzzy. I would like to know more about this, the function which determines the logic, if possible, and understand what partial_ratio in Python does.

Any information will be well welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code you can find a simple explanation of what does partial ratio in fuzzywuzzy does:

> Return the ratio of the most similar substring
> as a number between 0 and 100

In this code snippet you can find the differences

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
Out:    97

fuzz.partial_ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
Out:    100
```

[1] https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

[2] https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py